# How to flip multiple divs using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

How can I flip multiple `div`'s when I clicked on menus using CSS3?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Lucdd/) code is working for only the last two `div`s :

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
   <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
<section class="container">
   <div id="card">
      <div class="front flipper" id="home">home</div>
      <div class="back flipper" id="about">about</div>
      <div class="front flipper" id="work">work</div>
      <div class="back flipper" id="contact">contact</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**CSS Code**

```
    .container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    transform: rotateX( 180deg);
}
#card .flipper {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipper {
    background: #963
}
#card .front {
    background: red;
}
#card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX( 180deg);
    transform: rotateX( 180deg);
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
   $(".nav li").on("click", function() {

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    //  alert(activeTab);

    if ($("#card").hasClass("flipped")) {
        $("#card").removeClass("flipped");
    } else {
        $("#card").addClass("flipped");
    }

    return false;
});
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: note that you can change the whole if by toggleClass ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flip animation when used with two elements is a very simple one because there is one back side and one front side. But when the same needs to be implemented with many elements then it becomes extra complex because you need to maintain 3 states which are as follows:

- Flipped - This is when a block comes into view and the rotation is 0 degree (basically no rotation).
- Before - This is the state of elements which are prior to the flipped element. In this state the block is rotated 180 degree in one direction.
- After - This is the state of elements which are after the flipped element. In this state the block is rotated 180 degree in the opposite direction.

So basically when a link is clicked, the block before it is rotated from 0 to 180 degree, the target block itself is rotated from -180 degree to 0 degree (and next element remains at -180 degree). Doing these things provide it the look and feel of having a chain rotation.

```js
$(".nav li a").on("click", function() {
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
  $('#card > div').removeClass('flipped after before');
  $(activeTab).addClass('flipped');
  $(activeTab).prevAll('.flipper').addClass('before');
  $(activeTab).nextAll('.flipper').addClass('after');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.container {
   width: 500px;
   height: 360px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto 40px;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   -webkit-perspective: 800px;
   -moz-perspective: 800px;
   -o-perspective: 800px;
   perspective: 800px;
 }
 #card {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }
 #card .flipper {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 260px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 140px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s, opacity 1s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s, opacity 1s;
   -o-transition: -o-transform 1s, opacity 1s;
   transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   background: blue;
   opacity: 0;
 }
 #card .flipper:nth-child(2n) {
   background: red;
 }
 #card .flipper.flipped {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
   -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
   transform: rotateX(0deg);
   z-index: 1;
   opacity:1;
 }
 #card .flipper.before {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
   transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
 #card .flipper.after {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
   -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
   transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#home">home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">about</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#work">work</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <div class="flipper flipped" id="home">home</div>
    <div class="flipper after" id="about">about</div>
    <div class="flipper after" id="work">work</div>
    <div class="flipper after" id="contact">contact</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> **Note:** The jQuery code can be optimized further but I will leave the fine tuning part to you.

Comment: Nice answer, but there seems to be something wrong here. Click the last link (contact), before anything else and do `console.log($(activeTab).next('.flipper'));`. You will get a jQuery collection  with `length: 0` and the `after` class will be added to the prev sibling, which will break the animation.

Comment: @DavidDomain: Nice catch :) Let me see if I can do anything about it.

Comment: @DavidDomain: I have modified it a bit to make the animation work irrespective of the order. It requires a small opacity change though and I wasn't able to do it without that.

Comment: @JadChahine: You're welcome. Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```js
$(".nav li").on("click", function(){
    
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if($(activeTab).hasClass('current-flipper'))
        return;
    //  alert(activeTab);
    $("#card").find('div').removeClass('current-flipper');
    $(activeTab).addClass('current-flipper');
    $("#card").toggleClass("flipped");    
    return false;
});
```

```css
.flipper{
    display: none;
}

.current-flipper.flipper{
    display: block;
}

.container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 360px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      -webkit-perspective: 800px;
         -moz-perspective: 800px;
           -o-perspective: 800px;
              perspective: 800px;
    }

    #card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
           -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
              transition: transform 1s;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
           -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    #card.flipped {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX( 360deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateX( 360deg );
           -o-transform: rotateX( 360deg );
              transform: rotateX( 360deg );
    }

    #card .flipper {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 260px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 140px;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
           -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
.flipper{ background:#963}
#home{
    background:red;
}
#about{
    background:blue;
}
#work{
    background:green;
}
#contact{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
 <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>


 <section class="container">
    <div id="card">
      <div class="flipper current-flipper" id="home">home</div>
      <div class="flipper" id="about">about</div>
      <div class="flipper" id="work">work</div>
      <div class="flipper" id="contact">contact</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only seeing the last two because they're stacking on top of the first two. Essentially the cards themselves (elements with .front/.back classes) are staying still while you're rotating #card around them.

Perhaps you can try rotating the .front/.back elements independently. It means manually handling the interaction but in my opinion it'd easier to reason about.

Hope that helps